# Is this set equal to 3 points?

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

I tried to describe the following set:

$$ \{ z \in \mathbb C \mid \left| z - {\sqrt{2}\over 2}\right|^2 \left| z + {\sqrt{2}\over 2}\right|^2  = {1\over 4}\}$$

> Can you please tell me if my solution is correct?

$$ \left| z - {\sqrt{2}\over 2}\right|^2 \left| z + {\sqrt{2}\over 2}\right|^2  = {1\over 4}\}$$

if and only if

$$\left| (z - {\sqrt{2}\over 2} )(z + {\sqrt{2}\over 2})\right|^2  = {1\over 4}\}$$

if and only if

$$ |z^2 - {2 \over 4}|^2 = {1\over 4}$$

if and only if

$$ |z^2 - {1 \over 2}| = {1\over 2}$$

which is true if and only if $z \in \{0,1,-1\}$.

Comment: There are a lot more complex numbers at distance $1/2$ from $1/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is right till the conclusion.
$$\left| z^2-\frac{1}{2}\right| = \frac{1}{2}$$
implies:
$$ z^2 = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}e^{i\theta} = \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\theta}{2}} e^{i\theta/2}$$
so the solutions are given by:
$$ z=\pm\sqrt{\left|\cos(\theta/2)\right|} e^{i\theta/4}$$
for any $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot work out the equality $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}e^{i\theta} = \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\theta}{2}} e^{i\theta/2}$.

Comment: @Anna: compute the real and imaginary parts of $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}e^{i\theta}$ then write back this number in polar form.

Answer (score 0):

All seems pretty correct to me, except for the last step. Note that we are working in $\mathbb{C}$ here, so for instance $z=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}i+\frac{1}{2}}$ will work as well. The general solution for $z^2$ are all the points on a circle with radius $\frac{1}{2}$ around $\frac{1}{2}$. Now the general solution for $z$ would be to take all square roots (and minus square roots) of these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|z^2 - {1 \over 2}\right|^2 =\left|z^2 - {1 \over 2 }\right|\overline{\left|z^2 - {1 \over 2}\right|}= {1\over 4}$$
$$|z|^4-\frac12z^2-\frac12\bar{z}^2+\frac14=\frac14$$
$$|z|^4-\Re{(z^2)}=0.$$ Suppose $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ then we have $$r^4=r^2\cos 2\theta$$ That gives $r=0$ or $\cos 2\theta=\dfrac{1}{r^2}.$ Any complex number satisfying this relation is a solution for your locus.